# zeromq php extension for windows

Tags: php, zeromq, php-extension, zend-server

I am using Zend server configured with IIS 7.5. I searched for edit: zeromq php extension, I found these http://valokuva.org/builds/ and  http://snapshot.zero.mq/

I have tried to add extension in php.ini and when I enable it form zend admin it shows an error 
"The system could not load this extension" and in logs "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\php_zmq.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0".

I have tried to build extension (.dll) from source but it also didn't work. On http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:php its written

You will first need to install the ØMQ (2.1.x or higher recommended)

Do I have to install something first on my machine to use this extension as there is only source available or am I placing the file incorrectly?

Although I am running zeromq binding for python and is operating without problem.

Any help or guide is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else looking for this, I found it at:

```
https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq
```

Specifically:

```
https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/issues/62
http://178.79.157.189/~mikko/win32/php-zmq-win32.zip
```

Comment: i downloaded the dll and placed in the appropriate directory, still I am getting error in appache error log as follows "Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_zmq.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0" but that php_zmq.dll is ext folder

Comment: Wich php version are you using? did you restart apache service? did you dowload the zmq for php5? wich version of php are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it works, I just uploaded it: https://github.com/Polycademy/php_zmq_binaries

--EDIT--

All ZMQ extensions are now in: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/

Comment: Is there x64 version for 5.3.x available or do we have to upgrade php version for this ?

Comment: You'd have to ask the creator of the PHP ZMQ. Search github!

Comment: Ok, I searched and there is none. Either you have to build one or downgrade/upgrade accordingly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't use ZMQ on Windows, but on Linux, it also requires the uuid extension.

There's also a problem with also having the ImageMagick extension installed, because the uuid clashes between them. Ensuring that you load zmq before imagik is an effective workaround to that however.

Comment: Just saved me another few hours worth of headaches

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using dll from `php-zmq_zeromq-{version}-zts` folder fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found! Downloading from pear site
[[http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.1/windows]](http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.1/windows%5d)