# php zeromq extension: Unable to load dynamic library php_zmq.dll

Tags: php, xampp, zeromq, php-extension

I have **XAMPP** with **PHP Version 5.6.8**. I want to install zeromq extension.
Tried the following dlls from http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.2/windows.
Of course I have `extension=php_zmq.dll` in `\xampp\php\php.ini`

```
php_zmq-1.1.2-5.6-nts-vc11-x64
php_zmq-1.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x64

php_zmq-1.1.2-5.6-nts-vc11-x86
php_zmq-1.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86
```

Getting the error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.in 
Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: same question and more answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742773/zeromq-php-extension-for-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the dll worked for php 5.6.3. Details are in readme file

https://github.com/kirensiva/zmqPHPVersion5.6.3

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it working:
Download the http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.2/windows "5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x86" version.

Copy the php_zmq.dll to php/ext directory

Then copy the libzmq.dll to the xamp/ root directory

RESTART apache.